# Grab a List item based on newest datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime

Im grabing articles with this code.

```
List<view_M04FrontpagesEntity> fList = new view_M04FrontpagesService().GetByCategoryId(0);

var article = new M02ArticlesService().GetById(fList.First<view_M04FrontpagesEntity>().M02ArticleId);
```

I want to grab the article with the newest `article.UpdatedDate` how can a best do this with linq or other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended.

```
var m04FrontpagesEntities = new view_M04FrontpagesService().GetByCategoryId(0).ToList().Select(x => new M02ArticlesService().GetById(x.M02ArticleId)).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedDate); ;
var article = m04FrontpagesEntities.First();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `MaxBy` method provided my [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
List<view_M04FrontpagesEntity> fList = new view_M04FrontpagesService().GetByCategoryId(0);

var newest = fList.MaxBy(article => article.UpdatedDate);
```

Comment: Sorely missing from the BCL. +1

Comment: @voo no, in BCL there is only `Max` to which you can pass selector, but it will return the greatest `UpdatedDate`, but not **the article** with greates `UpdatedDate`. You have to install MoreLinq via NuGet package or just plain dlls from their site.

Answer (score 4):

you can Use OrderByDescending in LInQ.

```
var query = myList.Where(x =>x=="somePredicate")
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedDate ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = articles.OrderByDescending( a => a.UpdateDate ).First();
```

Generally speaking, this is it. You need to transfer this to your code yourself, because none of the code you posted helped.

Comment: You just chose the oldest article

Comment: @nvoigt Doesn't it required to have a descending order?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from article in fList
        orderby article.UpdatedDate descending
        select article).First();
```